# resolve() and then() comming first than async stuff

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, angular-promise, es6-promise

I read a guide about `promise` that says:

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

// Do some async stuff

// If async opp successful
resolve();

// If async opp fails
reject();

});
```

So, I'm trying to use that, but with no success:

```
let async = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  this.getPerson(page).subscribe( data => {
    console.log("First")
  });
  resolve();
})
async.then((result) =>{
  console.log("Last")
});
```

At console, I have the "Last" coming first, someone have a tip for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resolving promise before your query is completed. check below code for correct place of resolve

```
let async = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  this.getPerson(page).subscribe( data => {
    console.log("First");
    resolve(); // this is the expected place
  });
});
async.then((result) =>{
  console.log("Last")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `resolve();` should be within `this.getPerson(page).subscribe( data => {`

Like :

```
let async = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    this.getPerson(page).subscribe( data => {
      console.log("First") 
      resolve(); // called asap the result gets from api and above line executed
    });
    // resolve(); will be called before the above async function get's its response
});

async.then((result) =>{
    console.log("Last")
});
```

> Note : Don't use variable name such `async` , as it already reserved
>   keyword.

Comment: Thank you! Thats it :D, and thank you for your note.

Comment: @AlexGaspar , will you please accept the answer then as I have first given the answer and you can upvote multiple answer but accept only one , You have accept the answer first mine than Yogi , that make remove my naswer as accepted and you can upvote the answer after you got 15 up reps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the reserve `async` keyword, in the whole

```
 let async = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    this.getPerson(page).subscribe( data => {
      console.log("First") 
    });
    resolve();
        })
   async.then((result) =>{
     console.log("Last")
   });
```

You could rewrite your codes to this:

```js
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

// Do some async stuff

// If async opp successful
setTimeout(function(){
resolve(console.log("First") 
    )});
  });

promise.then((result) =>{
     console.log("Last")
   });
```

This should solve your problem.